# Low level version of transport.openOutputStream?

Tags: javascript, xulrunner, gecko

For load and stress testing a proxy I'm emulating a Firefox browser using XULRunner and [Crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar).

It works quite well and also melds in quite nicely with our (Perl) load+stress tool, which takes a list of destination-URLs and fires of as much HTTP GET load using `WWW::Curl` as I like.

However, what our perl-script stresstool also does (before I integrated it with crowbar) is choosing a source IP-address from a pool to emulate several different clients. Since crowbar is a proxy itself where you send all the requests to, I wanted to implement a HTTP-param to hand over the IP-address which should be used for outbound connections (let's say like `?ip=4.5.6.7`).

Going through crowbar's source code I noticed that it uses the JS-call `transport.openOutputStream`, which doesn't give you the possibility to chose the outbound IP-address.

Does anyone have an advice which (maybe native Gecko) function I should be using to chose one of the IP-addresses which are configured to the client-machine?
I'm kinda lost in all the documentation provided by Mozilla and just need the right nudge or a pointer where to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XULRunner/Firefox doesn't have the functionality to choose the outbound IP address - it will always go by the routing table of the operating system. So the outbound address is determined by the target address only. Best you could do is specifying a proxy in [nsISocketTransportService.createTransport()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISocketTransportService#createTransport%28%29).

Comment: OK, many thanks. I already kinda suspected this so I'll look into something else.